# How to implement multi select for large dataset in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a large data which should be dropdown values in a multiselect.

I tried using http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

But it is taking too long to load.

Please suggest a perfect way to implement this..

Comment: show your code, give explanations. You certainly have too much watches that we can't help you to spot without a piece of code

Comment: @deblaton The data I receive is in the form of list of objects like [{'id':21, 'value':'some'}]. It works nicely for small datasets but for large datasets it slows doen

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the component you're using, but the best way to implement a dropdown with huge amount of data is by using server filtering and minLength, in general:

- Min length means that you start showing suggestions after he has typed e.g. 3 letters.
- Server filtering means that you run a query per letter to the server, to show the suggestions needed for the dropdown. select * from people where name like '%' + value + '%'

Comment: Can you share some links so that I can understand the implementation details??

Comment: I don't have anything ready, but you can check this example from Kendo UI's elements: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/serverfiltering